# axiom of regularity and empty set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, axioms

So we have axiom of regularity which says that any set (let's call it $A$) has a subset $B$ such that $A\cap B = \emptyset$. But thinking about such sets as $C = \{1, 2\}$ and $D = \{3, 4\}$ we still have that $C\cap D = \emptyset$. So can it be that $\emptyset$ actually sometimes represents $2$ sets' common element (set) and sometimes represents that these $2$ sets are just disjoint? Or everything is ok with this symbolism?

Comment: To start with, you've got the axiom of regularity wrong. It says that any **nonempty** set $A$ (not just any set, it has to be nonempty) has an **element** (not subset) $B$ suth that $A\cap B=\emptyset$.

Comment: Regularity states that $A$ (if nonempty) has a **member** $B$ with $A\cap B=\emptyset$. That there is a subset of $A$ with this property doesn't require regularity. In any case, $\emptyset$ means only one thing: the set that has no members.

Comment: bof, yes you right. I just wanted to write a question shorter. ;)

Comment: My point of question was just about symbolism. I thought that if we do not knew anything about sets A and B (or element), but we knew that A∩B=∅ then what's happening there... Are they disjoint with all they subsets or disjoint just in one element. Whatever, stupid yes....

Comment: Well, $A\cap B := \{x: x\in A \wedge x\in B\}$-- that is, $y\in A\cap B \iff y\in A\wedge y\in B$--so if for all $y$, $y \notin A\cap B$, what does the logic tell you?

Comment: That A∩B is empty.

Comment: Indeed. Ok, thanks for answers. ;)

Comment: It also gives you that no $y$ is a member of both $A$ and of $B$. That tells you anything you need to know about what an empty intersection means. (sorry for the incorrect previous version of this comment; after work brain fuzzies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\emptyset$ is not a member of $A\cap B$. It ***is*** $A\cap B$. So $\emptyset$ represents the set of common elements of $A$ and $B$ but is not a common element itself. Also you got the axiom wrong as explained in comments.